# Extracting numbers from array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JavaScript question. I'm trying to extract numbers from a string where there are two rows separated with '\n' and each number is separated by ','.

In the first instance I want to get the first, the second, the third, the fourth and the fifth numbers. In the second instance I want the first and the sixth numbers.

My code so far:

```
var str = "1391,15,48,58,75,9300\n1687,76,65,23,34,9111"; 
var lines = str.split('\n');

$.each(lines, function () {
 var items = str.split(',');

  var foo = [],
     bar = [],
     foobar = str.length;

    for (i = 0; i < foobar; i++) {
        foo.push([parseFloat(str[i][0]), 
                   parseFloat(str[i][1]),
                   parseFloat(str[i][2]), 
                   parseFloat(str[i][3]), 
                   parseFloat(str[i][4])

         ]);

          bar.push([parseFloat(str[i][0]),
                   parseFloat(str[i][5])
           ]);

    }
});
```

The code does not work. I only get rubbish out. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

To complement Vergilius answer, this code now works:

```
var str = "1391,15,48,58,75,9300\n1687,76,65,23,34,9111"; 
var lines = str.split('\n');

var foo = []; var bar = [];

for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){

var items = lines[i].split(',');

foo.push([parseFloat(items[0]),
    parseFloat(items[1]),
    parseFloat(items[2]),
    parseFloat(items[3]),
    parseFloat(items[4])
]);

bar.push([parseFloat(items[0]),
    parseFloat(items[5])
]); 
}
```

Comment: don't use `str.length`, you could instead use `items.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "1391,15,48,58,75,9300\n1687,76,65,23,34,9111",
    lines = str.split('\n'), i, tmp, foo = [], bar = [];

for(i = 0; i <= lines.length - 1; i++) {
    tmp = lines[i].split(',');
    foo = tmp.filter(function(value, key) { if(key < 5) return true });
    bar = tmp.filter(function(value, key) { if(key == 0 || key == 5) return true });

}
```

should be okay, but you need still to parse items (try with another loop)